# Sanity project crashed after content update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sanity

My sanity io Desk and Vision tab used to work fine before I updated some fields in my Schema. After that i build and deploy the changes like I used to do before , but after that I am having an error.I`ve tried to restore the schema like it was before , but error remains...

The Desk tool crashed

```
Error: Workspace: missing context value
Error: Workspace: missing context value
    at DJ (https://avantgardeservice.sanity.studio/static/sanity-54893e46.js:7757:1969)
    at pr (https://avantgardeservice.sanity.studio/static/index-990e561a-d62f5f2c.js:187:1382)
    at FU (https://avantgardeservice.sanity.studio/static/sanity-54893e46.js:66:19598)
    at IL (https://avantgardeservice.sanity.studio/static/sanity-54893e46.js:68:3155)
    at E8e (https://avantgardeservice.sanity.studio/static/sanity-54893e46.js:68:44781)
    at $8e (https://avantgardeservice.sanity.studio/static/sanity-54893e46.js:68:39950)
    at yvt (https://avantgardeservice.sanity.studio/static/sanity-54893e46.js:68:39873)
    at T3 (https://avantgardeservice.sanity.studio/static/sanity-54893e46.js:68:39723)
    at VL (https://avantgardeservice.sanity.studio/static/sanity-54893e46.js:68:36071)
    at w8e (https://avantgardeservice.sanity.studio/static/sanity-54893e46.js:68:35017)
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "sanity-project",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "package.json",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "sanity dev",
    "start": "sanity start",
    "build": "sanity build",
    "deploy": "sanity deploy",
    "deploy-graphql": "sanity graphql deploy"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "sanity"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@sanity/vision": "^3.15.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-is": "^18.2.0",
    "sanity": "^3.15.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@sanity/eslint-config-studio": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.25",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.26",
    "eslint": "^8.6.0",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  },
  "prettier": {
    "semi": false,
    "printWidth": 100,
    "bracketSpacing": false,
    "singleQuote": true
  }
}
```

I`ve tried to restore the schema like it was before , but error remains...

Answer (score 0):

Sanity no longer provides free deploy.

You have to deploy on vercel, for example like this:

1. install Vercel CLI using `npm install -g vercel`
2. build your sanity studio by using  `sanity build`
3. login to vercel by running this command `vercel login`
4. for deploying run this command `vercel`